# How to prevent Serilog from logging every little step as information automatically?

Tags: c#, serilog

I want to use Serilog for my .Net 5 Web Api project. I installed the packages

- Serilog.AspNetCore v4.1.0
- Serilog.Sinks.Console v4.0.0

and changed the Program.cs file to

```
public sealed class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();
        
        CreateHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) 
        => Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
}
```

I created a single controller for testing purposes

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public sealed class TodosController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{todoId:Guid}")]
    public IActionResult GetTodoById(Guid todoId) => Ok(todoId);
}
```

After consuming this endpoint I can see the following in the console

```
[22:30:11 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
[22:30:11 INF] Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
[22:30:11 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[22:30:11 INF] Hosting environment: Development
[22:30:11 INF] Content root path: /home/.../Server
[22:30:12 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger - -
[22:30:12 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger - - - 301 0 - 78.0119ms
[22:30:12 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html - -
[22:30:12 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html - - - 200 - text/html;charset=utf-8 64.9042ms
[22:30:12 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/swagger-ui.css - -
[22:30:12 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js - -
[22:30:12 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js - -
[22:30:12 INF] Sending file. Request path: '/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js'. Physical path: 'N/A'
[22:30:12 INF] Sending file. Request path: '/swagger-ui.css'. Physical path: 'N/A'
[22:30:12 INF] Sending file. Request path: '/swagger-ui-bundle.js'. Physical path: 'N/A'
[22:30:12 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js - - - 200 986342 application/javascript 191.4506ms
[22:30:12 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js - - - 200 311804 application/javascript 191.4478ms
[22:30:12 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/swagger-ui.css - - - 200 142933 text/css 192.6142ms
[22:30:13 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json - -
[22:30:13 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json - - - 200 - application/json;charset=utf-8 83.3874ms
[22:30:41 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/Todos/00119201-3fed-4741-8295-48d697790729 - -
[22:30:41 INF] Executing endpoint 'Server.Controllers.TodosController.GetTodoById (Server)'
[22:30:41 INF] Route matched with {action = "GetTodoById", controller = "Todos"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] GetTodoById(System.Guid) on controller Server.Controllers.TodosController (Server).
[22:30:41 INF] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Guid'.
[22:30:41 INF] Executed action Server.Controllers.TodosController.GetTodoById (Server) in 34.6663ms
[22:30:41 INF] Executed endpoint 'Server.Controllers.TodosController.GetTodoById (Server)'
[22:30:41 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/Todos/00119201-3fed-4741-8295-48d697790729 - - - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 121.1434ms
```

I don't think this is a desired behaviour (if the log level is information instead of trace). Did I miss something? How to prevent Serilog from logging without being asked for it?

I already checked this question [Serilog - MinimumLoggingLevel Information shows every request in log - is that normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157418/serilog-minimumlogginglevel-information-shows-every-request-in-log-is-that-n) but that didn't help. The Serilog.Web.Classic package is not installed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These logs are being written by the ASP .NET host with the level `Information` and thus Serilog receives them as `Information` as well.

What you can do, is override the `MinimumLevel` for different sources, so that you can continue to receive `Information`-level logs written by some sources, whilst ignoring `Information`-level logs written by the host.

Here's an example that:

- Sets the overall `MinimumLevel` to `Information`
- Overrides the `MinimumLevel` to `Warning` only for logs coming from the `Microsoft` source
- Overrides the `MinimumLevel` to `Information` only for logs coming from the `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime` source

e.g.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
```

You can also configure these source overrides via `appSettings.json`:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set up log level for `"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"` and `"Microsoft"`. Personally I use [`Serilog.Settings.Configuration`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) package, adding `.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)` to the set up and copying values provided by default template to `Serilog.MinimumLevel.Override` json property in config:

```json
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up configuring the Serilog like this to hide the irrelevant information:

```json
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "Warning",
        // The migration is not applied, so what?
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations": "Warning",
        // DbCommand executed, so what?
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:/Logs/DEBUG-{Date}.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        },
        "When": "Environment = 'Development'"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:/Logs/RELEASE-{Date}.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        },
        "When": "Environment = 'Production'"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And the Program.cs:

```
using Serilog;
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    if (IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000", "https://0.0.0.0:5001");
                    }
                }).UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                {
                    loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
                });
        }
```

Output on executing "Home/Index":

```
[16:03:19 INF] Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5000
[16:03:19 INF] Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:5001
[16:03:19 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[16:03:19 INF] Hosting environment: Development
[16:03:19 INF] Content root path: O:\VCSharp\MVCSolution\MVCApplication
[16:03:22 INF] Executing endpoint 'MVCApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MVCApplication)'
[16:03:26 INF] Executed endpoint 'MVCApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MVCApplication)'
```